# sqlite.swift with Carthage

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, carthage, sqlite.swift

I'm using sqlite.swift in my Swift project. Until now I'm using Cocoapods to install/update the library.

Is it possible to install sqlite.swift with Carthage insted of using Cocoapods?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions from the `swift-2` branch? https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/swift-2#carthage

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't saw the swift-2 branch instructions

Comment: The only thing more amazing about the amazing SQLite.swift, is that it has carthage!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shared by stephencelis, you can follow the instructions detailed on [github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/](http://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/)

> Make sure Carthage is installed.
>   Update your Cartfile to include the following:
>
> `github "stephencelis/SQLite.swift"`
>
> Run `carthage update` and add the appropriate framework in Xcode.

This will install the latest version.